# Load Module on Node ID

Tags: nodes, webforms

My programming skills are really not up there.

I'm trying to load a module, and whatever instructions in there, only when a node ID is viewed.

I think I need to use hook node_load.

In other words, if Node ID of type webform is being viewed, load the following instructions from enabled custom module.

Comment: A module is installed. If you want to use the function of a module you need to include the file of the module. Using https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7 you can include file that contains the function you want to use. In order to use the functionality of a module you need to enable it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but I'm not sure I'm following. Please bare with me. I'm trying to create a module that will add customization to a particular webform based on if that webform is loaded, or viewed.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question is not clear at all, first because loading a module basing on the node being viewed is not something Drupal does; or a module is enabled, and then it is enabled whatever node is loaded, or it is not enabled. Secondly, _I need to use hook node_load_ doesn't make sense.

Comment: What!? No one wants to undress with me! C'mon! English is my second language... meaning that I know more that one language. Did I explained already that I have very basic programming skills and I'm just trying to learn something new here. Am I where I should be!?

Comment: You are @Daniel, it's just we have a high bar for quality here (trust me it's a good thing in the long run). We need questions to be really clear and specific, which I think you could do in this case by explaining what you mean by "load the following instructions"...if you described what those instructions need to do (perform an API request, alter something in the node's display, given that it's a webform maybe you need to alter the form) we'd be able to push you in a much better direction, and have something potentially more useful to future visitors :)

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'll try to provide better description on my next posts so that people like me can benefit from them. I just wasn't sure how to explain something I didn't fully understand. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is best to create a `hook_preprocess_node` in your custom module. There, you can check the node id and call the required functions.